# Can you please tell me all the episodes where madara uchiha appears?

Tags: naruto, anime-production

All madara uchiha appearance episodes in Naruto shippuden.

Comment: Surely the fandom has some kind of list like appears in episode X, mentioned only in episode Y, cameo episode Z ? Or not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a list questions that is considered too broad. We're not here to name every instance someone appears or is mentioned. Whether it be the actual Madara or not.

Answer (score 2):

I believe he makes his first appearance on episode 321 or 322. But he appears in 80 more episodes after that, so he is basically in almost every episode during the war.